# Можно ли заставить конструктор класса принимать только new параметр?

Tags: c++

Мне нужно реализовать иерархию классов, каждый содержит указатель на какой-то еще. И я хочу, чтоб при вызове конструктора, мои классы использовали только новую память. Возможно, я неверно формулирую, требуется следующее:

```
MyClass myobj(new AnotherClass());
```

То есть я хочу, чтоб можно было лишь так инициализировать объект и никак не:

```
AnotherClass* anotherobj = new AnotherClass();
MyClass myobj(anotherobj);
```

Хочу я так потому, что нужно избежать ситуации, когда мой класс проинициализирован указателем, который может быть удален вне объекта (тем самым уничтожив данные в моем объекте).

UPD: условие задачи:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Выделил красной рамкой условие, которое и заставило меня писать вопрос.

Comment: Принимайте `::std::unique_ptr<AnotherClass>`

Comment: А без умных указателей как-то можно тут обойтись?

Comment: А зачем? Умные указатели - это и есть решение. Возможно самодельные умные указатели, если чем-то не угодили стандартные. `new` и `delete` не должны вызываться руками, только внутри контейнеров и умных указателей.

Comment: Дело в том, что нужно без умных указателей сделать (ибо по программе они мол не пройдены в универе еще). Препод сказал "реализуйте все указатели без утечек памяти". Я подозреваю, что приведенный мною пример в вопросе, как раз демонстрирует утечку возможную.

Comment: Не вижу логики в постановке задачи: если `new` должен использоваться только в пределах объекта, то почему бы вызов `new` не перенести прямо в конструктор?

Comment: @user7860670 А кто мешает по дороге получить raw указатель из интеллектуального?...

Comment: По сути вы хотите обеспечить владение ресурсом. Если объект создаётся за пределами вашего класса, то его и уничтожить можно за пределами этого класса - вы не знаете есть ли где-либо ещё один указатель на данный объект. Для гарантии владения объектом нужно создавать объекты внутри вашего класса. Т.е. по вашему примеру объекты класса `AnotherClass` должны создаваться внутри `MyClass`. Ну или в `MyClass` делаете копию объекта на входе - но это двойной расход памяти.

Comment: @Harry просто по условию задачи, все классы, должны указатели принимать друг на друга. Там брался один базовый класс и от него надо было производные сделать. И вот они все принимают в конструктор оператор ```new```. Причем строятся именно как ```className(new somethingobj)```

Comment: Знаете, дайте условие исходной задачи. Без трактовки. А то это очень похоже на то, что вы спрашиваете не как забить гвоздь, а как именно держать микроскоп при забивании гвоздей...

Comment: @Harry добавил условие задачи в вопрос

Comment: Ну, откровенно — мне не нравится сама постановка все делать через `new` — зачем? Тут это явно излишне. Но если и делать через него, то вопрос в задаче не в том, чтоб не разрешить пользователю сделать плохо, а в том, чтоб ваша программа сама отрабатывала хорошо :) — без утечек и т.п. неприятностей. Стремиться сделать непробиваемую защиту от дурака можно, но, как говорится, "сделай программу, которой сможет пользоваться любой дурак — и только дурак будет ею пользоваться". По-моему, вы ставите перед собой излишнюю задачу.

Comment: @Harry ну это универская задачка)
Но да, скорее всего вы правы про излишность.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Передавайте указатель в конструктор через правостороннюю ссылку:

```
struct AnotherClass{};

struct MyClass{
    MyClass(AnotherClass *&&c):
        c{c}  //Если бы передавалась правосторонняя ссылка на объект AnotherClass, а не на указатель, то лучше написать так: c{std::move(c)}
    {}
    
    AnotherClass *c;
    
};

int main()
{
    MyClass myobj(new AnotherClass());

    AnotherClass* anotherobj = new AnotherClass();
    MyClass myobj1(anotherobj); //Ошибка: cannot bind rvalue reference of type ‘AnotherClass*&&’ to lvalue of type ‘AnotherClass*’
    
    return 0;
}
```

Другой вопрос, что раз вы не проходили `unique_ptr`, то и `rvalue references`, наверное, тоже.

Comment: Считать ли `MyClass myobj1(anotherobj + 0);` нарушением требования или нет? результат `new` как передан в конструктор, так и остался в переменной... Молчу про вызов в качестве аргумента функции, возвращающей указатель, а как побочное действие сохраняющий его где-то...